# Should I do either push or pull first?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

Please imagine this:

My co-worker and I are working on the master branch. I've changed (added and removed) some code. At the same time my co-worker did some changes and pushed a `commit` to the master branch.

Now my current working directory is different than master branch and I want to keep both the changes on the master branch and my working directory.

What should I do in this case?

If I do a push, the master branch will be the same as my working directory *(my co-worker's changes will be gone)*, If I do a pull first, naturally all my changes will be gone. Anyway, how can I handle such situation?

Comment: If you pull, your changes are not _lost_, they are **merged**

Comment: @Edmundo Really?! So I have to do a pull first?

Comment: ```git pull origin``` (or whatever the other repo name is). https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: @Edmundo I see, thank you. *(however still I scare to run that command, since I cannot rewrite all my changes agian)*

Comment: depending on you settings `pull` equals to `fetch`+`merge` (default) or `fetch`+`rebase` - so per default it would fetch the new stuff from master, then merge it with your stuff, you may get a conflict iff there's a conflict.

Comment: do you _have_ to pull first? Under normal conditions: Yes. You want to include your changes along your friend's changes, don't you? That's normally done by merging (or rebasing). But there are other situations where you might just say: _You know what? I don't want to see those changes on the branch_. It's not something you will encounter everyday... but still possible. In that case you won't pull.

Comment: also, if you you are paranoid, just branch out `git checkout -b save-my-stuff` and/or additionally peek into `git reflog` doc

Comment: You can run it without any problem. Your previous revisions will stay on the repo. You can always go back to them if you don't like the results. It's git, not svn so you can do a lot of nice things to make stuff you don't like disappear. take a look at ```git reflog```

Comment: Have you committed your changes? You should do it first.

Comment: @max630 If I don't do that *(even I don't add my changes to the stage)* and then do a pull, what happens?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it is very risky overall to perform any manipulations without having your changes committed or at least stashed. In this case it can, for example, offer you to run with `--force` and if you do you will lose your changes. It could even do it by itself with some version or configuration settings. Having them in stage (aka index) would not help much because after reset they would be some orphaned blobs in object database without even path information.

Answer (score 6):

Neither your changes nor the changes of your co-worker can get lost so easily when using Git. Once something is committed, it takes some effort to actually delete those committed changes again. That's one of the beautiful aspects of Git.

In the situation you describe, you won't be able to push anyway, because Git will detect that there are changes in the remote repository that are not available in your local repository. You are going to have to fetch those changes and then either merge them in or rebase your changes on top of the ones fetched from the remote repository.

To make it easy, you should probably do a `git pull`. Git will automatically merge your co-workers changes into your working copy, if possible. If your co-workers and your own changes conflict in a more complicated way, you'll have to merge the changes manually. But that should actually not happen very often if both of you follow a structured Git workflow.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you've committed the code locally, You should first do:

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

This will fetch the code from remote and rebase it. Once this is done, simply push back the code to remote.

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Is using `--rebase` mandatory? What happens if I don't use it? What it does exactly?

Comment: @MartinAJ No, `--rebase` is not mandatory. `git pull` is a combination of `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. `--rebase` simply uses `rebase` instead of `merge`. So, in the end, it all depends on your preference on merge vs rebase. Personally I am more comfortable with merge when there are a lot of commits  and conflicts and rebase when the branches diverge by only a few simple commits.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` runs `git fetch` with the given parameters and calls `git merge` to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch.

[source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Pull first. Your contribution will not be lost. Thats the advantage of version control systems. It allows big team to work on code teams at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Before we can push our changes to your branch in git-hub, we need to make sure our local repository have all changes that have been made to git-hub. The correct next step is to pull. This can work one of two ways:

1. Traditional `pull`: A merge command will combine the remote changes
   with our local changes. This will add a new commit, and the
   changelist should depict that the separate lines of development have
   come back together.
2. `Pull+rebase`: If wecheck the `re-base` option, `Hg/Git` will
   temporarily undo ("rewind") any changes from new local commits,
   `fast-forward` so the local branch is identical to the remote, then
   redo ("replay") the local `changes/commits` to the new `HEAD` of the
   branch. This will change the timestamps of your local commits, but
   the changelist should depict that all changes happened linearly. In
   either case, there is a chance we need to resolve conflicts if
   we happenned to change any overlapping pieces of
   code in your latest `commits`.